# I made some auto form code meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I made some auto form code

Problem is

```
autoValue: ->
  @_id
```

is not work..

form are made but not sumited

do you guys know why?

```
Comments.insert
      createAt: new Date
      body: tmpl.find('textarea#com').value
      todoId: @_id

@Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments')
Comments.attachSchema new SimpleSchema
  comments:
    type: String
    max: 100
    label: 'CommentsBody'
  commentsId:
    label: 'CommentsId'
    type: String
    autoValue: ->
      @_id
    autoform:
      omit: true
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate ID field on the `Comments` collection? The ID is already saved in the database as `_id`.

Comment: I need save a posts _id to match comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema and your insert method does not match. Also, doing an autovalue -> @_id is redundant as it will save _id twice, once in the _id field and once in the commentsId. 
This is the schema that should work with your method:

```
Comments.attachSchema new SimpleSchema
  body:
    type: String
    max: 100
    label: 'CommentsBody'
  createAt:
    type: Date
    autoValue: ->
      if @isInsert
          new Date()
    autoform:
      omit: true
  todoId:
    type: String
```